# bird's eye view in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with a monocular camera in real time, and I'm trying to recover a bird's eye view to detect road lines. I'm using opencv libraries in python and I used the function warpPerspective to get  the transformed image.

Now, I get the bird eye view image. But, the lines are not parallel and the image has a trapezoidal shape. I don't knew which function permit to retrieve the parallel image.

The code is joint below.

Note : I'm working in ROS.

```py
i=0

#declare rotation angles

phi = -80*math.pi/180
#tangage
theta = -0*math.pi/180
#roulis
psi = -(0+90)*math.pi/180
#lacet

mu = 0*math.pi/180
#tangage supplimentaire
zeta = 0*math.pi/180
#roulis suplimentaire

hc = 500

#declare rotation matrix

Rphi = [[1,0,0,0],
      [0,math.cos(phi),-math.sin(phi),0],
      [0,math.sin(phi),math.cos(phi),0],
      [0,0,0,1]]

Rzeta = [[1,0,0,0],
      [0,math.cos(zeta),-math.sin(zeta),0],
      [0,math.sin(zeta),math.cos(zeta),0],
      [0,0,0,1]]

Rtheta = [[math.cos(theta),0,math.sin(theta),0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [-math.sin(theta),0,math.cos(theta),0],
        [0,0,0,1]]

Rmu = [[math.cos(mu),0,math.sin(mu),0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [-math.sin(mu),0,math.cos(mu),0],
        [0,0,0,1]]

Rpsi = [[math.cos(psi),math.sin(psi),0,0],
      [-math.sin(psi),math.cos(psi),0,0],
      [0,0,1,0],
      [0,0,0,1]]

T = [[0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,hc],
   [0,0,0,0]]

K = [[1617.442,0,664.520,0],
   [0,1622.176,490.369,0],
   [0,0,1,0]]

K2 = [[0,1,-664.520],
    [1,0,-490.369],
    [0,0,10],
    [0,0,1]]

rot = np.dot(Rzeta,Rmu)
Rrot1 = np.dot(Rphi,np.dot(Rtheta,Rpsi))
Rrot2 = np.dot(Rrot1,rot)

Rrot3 = np.add(Rrot2,T)
#matrice de transformation
G1 = np.dot(K,np.dot(Rrot3,K2))

#G1 = np.dot(K,np.dot(T,np.dot(Rrot2,K2)))
G = inv(G1)

dist_vect = np.array([-0.4417, 0.9801, -0.000189, 0.0002, -3.1882])

mtx_vect = np.array([[1617.442,0,664.520],
          [0,1622.176,490.369],
          [0,0,1]])

img_size = [1280,964]








def image_callback(msg):
   global i
   print("Received an image!")
   try:
   # Convert your ROS Image message to OpenCV2
       cv2_img = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


   rospy.sleep(1)
   except CvBridgeError, e:
       print(e)
   else:
   exists = os.path.isfile('./camera_image'+str(i)+'.png')

   if exists:
       # Save your OpenCV2 image as a png 
       i+=1
       dst = cv2.undistort(gray, mtx_vect, dist_vect, None, mtx_vect)
       transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(dst, G, (1280, 964), cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP + cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
           cv2.imwrite('camera_image'+str(i)+'.png', transformed)
       print("image enregistrer num ", str(i))

   else : 
       cv2.imwrite('camera_image0.png', transformed)
       print("image enregistrer num ", str(i))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please add some input images you use as output, what output you get and what is the expected output. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, Thank's for replying. I'm new at SO. I can't find the way to add images. Can you tell me :!

Comment: @AFETTOUCHEMassinissa https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/369874 has instructions on how to upload images.